# Chat Bot Invocable Actions

Tags: liveagent, einstein, bots, snap-ins

I am planning to configure ChatBot with invocable actions. I am not getting the output instead it says "Sorry, I didn't understand that". I tested in console, I am getting the output.

Am I missing anything else?

If I return some

```
public with sharing class ChatBotContact {
     public class ChatBotContactEmailInput {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String EmailId;
    }

    public class ChatBotContactEmailOutput {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String conFirstName;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String conLastName;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String phone;
    }

    @InvocableMethod(label='Get Contact Details' description='Returns Contact Information')
    public static List<ChatBotContactEmailOutput> getContactDetails(List<ChatBotContactEmailInput> inputs) {
        Contact c = [SELECT Id, FirstName, Email, LastName, MobilePhone FROM Contact WHERE Email =: inputs[0].EmailId];

        List<ChatBotContactEmailOutput> results = new List<ChatBotContactEmailOutput>();
        ChatBotContactEmailOutput item = new ChatBotContactEmailOutput();
        item.conFirstName = c.FirstName;
        item.conLastName = c.LastName;
        item.phone = c.MobilePhone;
        results.add(item);

        return results;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, the issue was in the slot Names and assigning the values in the method were wrong.

All good now.